# How can I identify what is causing my GCFI to short

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a GCFI outlet with another outlet and an extractor fan coming off it. It seems to randomly get tripped every week or so.

How can I diagnose what is causing it to trip? If it is thinning insulation on the wires are there any electricians tools that can identify this so that I don't have to tear open all the walls?

Thanks in advance.

Chema

Comment: To test, run an adequately sized extension cord from a different GFCI to power the extractor fan.  Does the old circuit continue to trip?  Does the alternate GFCI trip?

Comment: I agree intermittently tripping GFCI's are a pain. Motor loads do shorten there life. I have changed hundreds on garbage disposals. I would just replace it.

Comment: It's NOT wires.  Insulation doesn't thin.   Wires in walls are almost never the problem unless you've been sticking nails in the walls.   It's virtually always at wire ends, or in devices connected to wires.  This is an area of denial for many; they presume that surely my device cannot be ground faulting.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the outlet coming off the GCFI is also a GCFI. Apparently doubling up like that can cause problems. Also, the GCFI that keeps tripping is quite old. I'll try your recommendations and report back. Thank you.